# Is it possible to easily eliminate this reduce/reduce conflict?

Tags: python, if-statement, parsing, sly

This is my code for if statements that might have elses or elsifs for the scripting language I'm writing a parser for. I'm actually rather proud of how compact I got it:

```
@_( 'IF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set { elsif_statement } ENDIF',
    'IF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set { elsif_statement } ELSE NEWLINE statement_set ENDIF',
    )
def if_statement(self, p):
    expressions = []
    expressions.append((p.expr_comp, p[6]))
    else_statement = None
    if (p[8] == 'else'):
        else_statement = p[10]

    expressions.extend(p.elsif_statement)

    return ('IF', expressions, else_statement)

@_('ELSIF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set')
def elsif_statement(self, p):
    return (p.expr_comp, p.statement_set)
```

This generates the following rules:

> Rule 64    if_statement -> IF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set _3_elsif_statement_repeat ELSE NEWLINE statement_set ENDIF
> Rule 65    _3_elsif_statement_repeat -> _3_elsif_statement_items
> Rule 66    _3_elsif_statement_repeat -> 
> Rule 67    _3_elsif_statement_items -> _3_elsif_statement_items _3_elsif_statement_item
> Rule 68    _3_elsif_statement_items -> _3_elsif_statement_item
> Rule 69    _3_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement
> Rule 70    if_statement -> IF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set _4_elsif_statement_repeat ENDIF
> Rule 71    _4_elsif_statement_repeat -> _4_elsif_statement_items
> Rule 72    _4_elsif_statement_repeat -> 
> Rule 73    _4_elsif_statement_items -> _4_elsif_statement_items _4_elsif_statement_item
> Rule 74    _4_elsif_statement_items -> _4_elsif_statement_item
> Rule 75    _4_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement
> Rule 76    elsif_statement -> ELSIF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set

Unfortunately, it also generates the following conflicts:

```
Conflicts:    

reduce/reduce conflict for ELSIF in state 111 resolved using rule _3_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement
rejected rule (_4_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement) in state 111
   reduce using _3_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement with lookahead ELSIF
   ╭╴
   │ elsif_statement ♦          ELSIF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set
   │ ╰_3_elsif_statement_item╯  ╰elsif_statement───────────────────────────────────────╯
   │ ╰_3_elsif_statement_items╯ ╰_3_elsif_statement_item───────────────────────────────╯
   │ ╰_3_elsif_statement_items─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
   ╰╴

   reduce using _4_elsif_statement_item -> elsif_statement with lookahead ELSIF
   ╭╴
   │ elsif_statement ♦          ELSIF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set
   │ ╰_4_elsif_statement_item╯  ╰elsif_statement───────────────────────────────────────╯
   │ ╰_4_elsif_statement_items╯ ╰_4_elsif_statement_item───────────────────────────────╯
   │ ╰_4_elsif_statement_items─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
   ╰╴
```

The code works, but I'm trying to have as few conflicts as possible so that actual problems don't get lost in the noise. I suspect that part of the problem is the automation used for an optional list of items, but my brain is not catching exactly how this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different productions which include ´{ elsif_statement }´. The EBNF expander creates two different non-terminals; it does not attempt to notice that they are the same. That creates a conflict, because the parser can't know which of the two identical non-terminals to use without looking ahead to the `elsif` or `end`, which it obviously can't do.

There are a number of fixes for this. A simple one is to change `elsif_statement`, which recognises a single `elsif` clause, to instead  recognise a sequence of `elsif` clauses.

Comment: Doing that way does get rid of the elsif, albeit at the cost of making for a much more hairy access to the contents. I will continue fiddling with it. Thank you.

Comment: @sean: I don't see why it should make it any more difficult to access contents. You just need `elsif_statement_list`  to return a list of tuples, and then you don't need to change the action for the `if_statement` at all. In fact, you could simply add the production `elsif_statement_list : { elsif_statement }`, and it should all work. (Personally, I'd get rid of the duplication if `if_statement` as a first option, but I don't think Sly does optionals. Although writing it out in BNF is not at all challenging.)

Comment: Huh. I had thought I'd done that implementation of an elsif_statement_list and had even more conflicts. I found a better way to state the code to bring it down to one rule. I'll post that as my answer, although yours will remain the accepted one. Incidentally, Sly (at least the version I have) does have the optional EBNF notation, as well as the optional list.

Answer (score 0):

rici's help was invaluable to me finding a way to even further condense the code:

```
@_('IF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set elsif_statement_list optional_else ENDIF')
def if_statement(self, p):
    expressions = []
    expressions.append((p.expr_comp, p.statement_set))
    else_statement = p.optional_else
    
    expressions.extend(p.elsif_statement_list)

    return ('IF', expressions, else_statement)

@_('[ ELSE NEWLINE statement_set ]')
def optional_else(self, p):
    return p.statement_set

@_('{ elsif_statement }')
def elsif_statement_list(self, p):
    return p.elsif_statement

@_('ELSIF LPAREN expr_comp RPAREN THEN NEWLINE statement_set')
def elsif_statement(self, p):
    return (p.expr_comp, p.statement_set)
```

No reduce conflicts, and I got rid of a number of indexed checks. Incidentally, putting the `else` and `elsif` constructs into their own non-terminals helped a lot with that. My original statement of it, with more than one rule leading into the function, meant that multiple `statement_set` items would mean that under one rule, there would be one `p.statement_set` and in another, there would be `p.statement_set0` and `p.statement_set1`. Since the optional and repetition constructs return None or an empty list if the item isn't present, I can just check that. And sticking them inside the non-terminal means I can reference `p.elsif_statement_list` instead of something like `_3_elsif_statement_repeat` or having to use an index when accessing the value (and if you embed multiple symbols into the curly braces instead of a non-terminal, it gets even messier with multiple levels of reference to get the the actual field you want).

Hopefully, this will help someone else out implementing a similar construct.